how to show api data in wordpress?
I want a plugin to receive a nested json file from a url and display its information in the form of paged cards with ajax search capability.
Is there such a plugin?
I tested the wpDataTable plugin, but it is displayed as a table. I want it to be displayed as paginated cards with search capability.

I am afraid there is not plugin available to meet this requirement, but you can achieve this with the help of custom development.
This can be done using three steps:

We need to Fetch and Process JSON Data using WP AJAX.
We need to create a JavaScript File for AJAX and Display.
We need to create HTML Structure to display cards.

Step 1: Place the given code in functions.php file of your theme.
<?php

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_custom_script_files' );
function enqueue_custom_script_files() {
    wp_enqueue_script('custom-ajax-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/custom-ajax.js', array('jquery'), null, true);
    wp_localize_script('custom-ajax-script', 'ajax_object', array('ajax_url' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php')));
}

add_action( 'wp_ajax_fetch_json_data', 'fetch_api_json_data' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_fetch_json_data', 'fetch_api_json_data' );
function fetch_api_json_data()
{
    $response = wp_remote_get('URL_TO_YOUR_JSON_FILE');
    if ( is_wp_error($response) ) {
        echo json_encode( array('error' => 'Unable to retrieve data') );
    } else {
        $data = wp_remote_retrieve_body( $response );
        echo $data;
    }
    wp_die();
}

Step 2: Here are adding AJAX code inside JS file.


jQuery(document).ready( function ($) {
    function fetchData( page = 1, searchQuery = '' ) {
        $.ajax({
            url   : ajax_object.ajax_url,
            type  : 'POST',
            data  : {
                action: 'fetch_json_data',
                page  : page,
                search: searchQuery
            },
            success: function (response) {
                let data = JSON.parse( response );
                if ( data.error ) {
                    $( '#card-container' ).html( '<p>' + data.error + '</p>' );
                } else {
                    displayCards( data );
                }
            }
        });
    }

    function displayCards(data) {
        let container = $( '#card-container' );
        container.empty();
        data.forEach(item => {
            let card = `<div class="card">
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h5 class="card-title">${item.title}</h5>
                                <p class="card-text">${item.description}</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>`;
            container.append(card);
        });
    }

    // Initial we are fetching data here.
    fetchData();

    // Search functionality is here.
    $('#search-input').on('keyup', function () {
        let searchQuery = $(this).val();
        fetchData(1, searchQuery);
    });

    // Pagination code is here.
    $( document ).on( 'click', '.pagination a', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        let page = $(this).data( 'page' );
        fetchData(page);
    });
});



Step 3: Here we are adding HTML to display Cards layout.


<div id="card-container" class="row"></div>
<input type="text" id="search-input" placeholder="Search Data">
<div class="pagination">
    <a href="#" data-page="1">Card 1</a>
    <a href="#" data-page="2">Card 2</a>
    <a href="#" data-page="3">Card 3</a>
    <!-- Add more pagination links as needed -->
</div>



Please let me know if this helps.
